# WCF Service gives 403 error after some calls

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, service, wcf-binding

I have written a WCF service. The problem i face is the call to the service works only 3-4 times after the service is published. After that any calls to the service returns 403 error. I have checked the timeout variables in config files and set them to 5 minutes. But still the issue persists.

**Config file (Server side)**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474083647" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="83808608" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="409600000" maxNameTableCharCount="163840000" />



    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="409600000" maxNameTableCharCount="163840000"/>

    </binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>
 </bindings>

 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="servicebehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restbehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>


 <services>
  <service name="WcfJMMLib.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http:address" />

      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfJMMLib.IService1">


      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior" contract="WcfJMMLib.IService2"/>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>        

  </service>
  </services>

 </system.serviceModel>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
</defaultProxy>
<connectionManagement>
  <add maxconnection = "100" address ="*" />
</connectionManagement>
 </system.net>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: this problem happen in service hosted machine or other machine ?
i means where from you trying to open your service ?

Comment: Both. I have hosted the WCF service on one machine. I get this error while calling the service from different machine as well as the hosted machine. Everything works fine for first 3-4 calls. Then it starts giving 403 error

Comment: please turn off windows firewall and try. if it works it me know

Comment: this may help you http://pcsupport.about.com/od/browsers/fl/http-403-forbidden.htm

Comment: If it's hosted in IIS, you can try adding FailedRequestTrace log to get more information. In addition, sniff the calls which invoke the web service (E.g. via fiddler) and compare it, maybe something changes in the request which causes the 403, and it is not necessarily something in your web service.

Comment: Its not firewall issue. The service itself stops after sometime. Did a check by entering the .svc path on the browser. Restarting the App Pool in IIS also doesnt solve the issue. However as soon as the config files get replaced (On publishing) the issue gets resolved